Highcharts Treegraph: How to set the style of each node
How to set the style of each node, such as border and border shadow
No configuration of node styles in the document was found.
It is best to have complete configuration item code.
Or if you have a document address, you can send it to me for reference. Thank you.

You can style the appearance of nodes in treegraph series with marker object, e.g. by setting lineWidth, lineColor or setting your own symbol.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z5t4gaem/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treegraph.marker
